# Vizio M43-C1 as a monitor 4k @ 60hz graphics card options

Tags: hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, 4k-resolution

I have been scratching my head all day like crazy trying to figure this out.

I bought a Vizio M43-C1 TV to be used as a monitor and has 1 X  4k @ 60hz HDMI port but unfortunately no DisplayPort. Now, I need to upgrade my graphics card on my PC. I was thinking of getting the GTX 750 Ti. Will I be ok to simply use a DP 1.2->HDMI 2.0 adapter so I can get 3840 x 2160 @ 60 Hz?

Edited: I am only doing programming, gaming not important.

Answer (score 1):

After more and more reading, this TV is not recommended as a PC Monitor since it does not do chroma 4:4:4 at 4k @ 60hz. I am stuck @ 30hz.

[M43-C1 TV Review](http://www.rtings.com/tv/reviews/vizio/m-series-2015/settings)